# C++ , return string from function; boost::asio read / write

Tags: c++, string, boost, boost-asio

I get a compile error, additionally I cannot boost::asio::read buf without giving it array elements.

```
std::string eport::read_data (void)
{
    io_service io;  // create the I/O service that talks to the serial device
    serial_port port (io, PORT);    // create the serial device, note it takes the io service and the port name
    error_code ec;  // address used for error checking
    std::string buf [100];  // data with crc on end

    try
    {
        read (port, buffer (buf), ec);
        std::cout << "eport::read: result: " << buf << std::endl;
    }
    catch (error_code &ec)
    {
        std::cout << "eport::read: ERROR: " << ec << std::endl; 
        return "error";
    }

    std::cout << "eport::read: SUCCESS" << std::endl;

    return buf;
```

The error:

```
eport.cc:83:9: error: could not convert ‘(std::string*)(& buf)’ from ‘std::string* {aka std::basic_string<char>*}’ to ‘std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}’
```

Does the function need to be cast as const char* ?  I am not sure what is wrong.  Any help is appreciated, thank you.

**UPDATED CODE**

This is my code.  I hope it can help someone because asio lacks good examples on the web.  I know my write function could be written better, and this code has not been tested so I'm not sure if I'm doing this right or not.  Thanks.

```
#include "../include/main.H"
#include <boost/asio.hpp>   // asynchronous input/output
#include <boost/crc.hpp>    // cyclic redundancy code (for data checking)

using namespace::boost::system;
using namespace::boost::asio;

const char *PORT = "/dev/ttyS0";

// serial port communication setup
serial_port_base::baud_rate BAUD (9600);    // what baud rate do we communicate at (default is 9600)
serial_port_base::character_size C_SIZE (8);    // how big is each "packet" of data (default is 8 bits)
serial_port_base::flow_control FLOW (serial_port_base::flow_control::none); // what flow control is used (default is none)
serial_port_base::parity PARITY (serial_port_base::parity::none);   // what parity is used (default is none)
serial_port_base::stop_bits STOP (serial_port_base::stop_bits::one);    // how many stop bits are used (default is one)

int eport::initialize (void)
{
    io_service io;  // create the I/O service that talks to the serial device
    serial_port port (io, PORT);    // create the serial device, note it takes the io service and the port name

    // set serial port options
    port.set_option (BAUD);
    port.set_option (C_SIZE);
    port.set_option (FLOW);
    port.set_option (PARITY);
    port.set_option (STOP);

    return 0;
}

int eport::write_data (std::string data)
{
    io_service io;  // create the I/O service that talks to the serial device
    serial_port port (io, PORT);    // create the serial device, note it takes the io service and the port name
    error_code ec;  // address used for error checking
    boost::crc_32_type crcresult;   // used for communication checking
    char buf [1024];    // buffer to hold data
    int crc;    // holds crc value
    std::ostringstream convert; // used to convert int to string
    std::string data_crc;   // data with crc on end
    std::stringstream ss;   // used to add strings

    strncpy (buf, data.c_str(), sizeof(buf));   // put data into buffer
    buf [sizeof(buf) - 1] = 0;  // make sure the last element has a null

    crcresult.process_bytes (buf, sizeof(buf)); // get crc value from buffer contents
    crc = crcresult.checksum(); // put crc value into integer
    convert << crc; // convert integer to string
    ss << data << convert.str ();   // add crc string to data string
    data_crc = ss.str ();   // data string with crc appended to be used in reading / writing
    std::cout << "eport::write: data with crc: " << data_crc << std::endl; 

    std::cout << "eport::write: writing: " << data_crc << std::endl; 
    write (port, buffer (data_crc, sizeof(data_crc)), ec);  // write data with crc to serial device

    if (ec) // if error code is true, print and return
    {
        std::cout << "eport::write: ERROR: " << ec << std::endl; 
        return -1;
    }

    std::cout << "eport::write: SUCCESS" << std::endl;

    return crc;
}

std::string eport::read_data (void)
{
    io_service io;  // create the I/O service that talks to the serial device
    serial_port port (io, PORT);    // create the serial device, note it takes the io service and the port name
    error_code ec;  // address used for error checking
    streambuf sb;   // asio stream buffer to hold read data
    std::string buf;    // read buffer will be put into this string

    size_t transferred = read (port, sb, ec);   // read data from serial device
    buf.resize (transferred);   // resize the string to the read data size
    sb.sgetn (&buf[0], buf.size ());    // stores characters from the stream to the array
    std::cout << "eport::read: result: " << buf << std::endl;

    if (ec)
    {
        std::cout << "eport::read: ERROR: " << ec << std::endl; 
        return "error";
    }

    std::cout << "eport::read: SUCCESS" << std::endl;

    return buf;
}
```

Comment: In your `read` function, how do you know the number of characters that are actually read?  This is a hole in your code that you need to explain before a good answer can be given.

Comment: @MattMcNabb `boost::asio::buffer` adaptor function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The most generic way would be use a `asio::streambuf`

   ```
   streambuf sb;
   size_t transferred = read (port, sb, ec);
   ```

   According to the docs:

   > This function is used to read a certain number of bytes of data from a stream. The call will block until one of the following conditions is true:
   >
   > - The supplied buffer is full (that is, it has reached maximum size).
   > - An error occurred.
   >
   > This operation is implemented in terms of zero or more calls to the stream's `read_some` function.

   Then, copy it to a string:

   ```
   std::string buf;
   buf.resize(transferred);
   sb.sgetn(&buf[0], buf.size());
   ```

   ---
2. Alternatively, preallocate a buffer of the expected size:

   ```
   std::string buf(100u, '\0');
   size_t transferred = read (port, buffer(buf), ec);
   buf.resize(transferred);
   ```

   ---
3. For more complicated scenarios, use `read_until`:

   ```
   streambuf sb;
   size_t transferred = read_until(port, sb, "\r\n", ec);
   ```

   This will read until `"\r\n"` was encountered (note: may read more than that, but won't invoke `read_some` again after seeing the delimiter).

   ---
4. Even more complicated stop conditions could use the [overload that takes a `MatchCondition` functor](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/read_until/overload8.html).

### Note on exception handling

If you pass `ec` to receive the `error_code` there will be no exceptions thrown

Comment: Clever answer.  I will use your first approach, it compiles fine for me. I will post my updated program when done.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`buf` is an array of `std::string`. You should change your prototype or return just one string. `buf[0]` for example.

Most possibly what you want is:

```
std::string buf;  // No [100]
```

Comment: yes you're right, thank you; for some reason I was thinking each element held a character like a char array, but each string element can hold a lot of text right?

Comment: Yes you are right. Check [Example](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%2B)

Comment: that makes sense; but then buffer (buf) gives me compile errors; perhaps I will make a seperate variable for that and put it into the string

Comment: In that case, you should use `unsigned char buf[MAX_BUF_SIZE];` or `std::vector<unsigned char> buf(MAX_BUF_SIZE);` and pass `&buf[0]` as read argument.

Comment: that is better than char buf [1024] ?

Comment: Depending upon the requirements and nature of other APIs, one form may be more or less advantageous over another.

Comment: @MohitJain Asio expects a buffer, not the pointer to a first element (as that would give no information about buffer size)

Answer (score 1):

There are issues with your code that you will need to answer, more specifically, how do you know the number of characters that will be sent to your `read` function?

However, the general answer to your question is to use a character array, and then return this as the std::string:

```
std::string eport::read_data (void)
{
    io_service io;  // create the I/O service that talks to the serial device
    serial_port port (io, PORT);    // create the serial device, note it takes the io service and the port name
    error_code ec;  // address used for error checking
    char buf [100];  // data with crc on end

    try
    {
        read (port, buf, ec);
        std::cout << "eport::read: result: " << buf << std::endl;
    }
    catch (error_code &ec)
    {
        std::cout << "eport::read: ERROR: " << ec << std::endl; 
        return "error";
    }

    std::cout << "eport::read: SUCCESS" << std::endl;

    return buf;
}
```

The `std::string` constructor will take care of copying the `buf` at the end to a std::string.

Now, if there is a way to determine the number of characters read, then the function has to be written differently.  Most `read` functions have a parameter specifying the maximum number of characters to read, and somewhere it is returned the number of characters that are read.

Assuming you could rewrite (or call) a different read function that has both of these properties, the code would look like this:

```
std::string eport::read_data (void)
{
    io_service io;  // create the I/O service that talks to the serial device
    serial_port port (io, PORT);    // create the serial device, note it takes the io service and the port name
    error_code ec;  // address used for error checking
    char buf [100];  // data with crc on end
    int numCharsRead = 0;
    try
    {
        numCharsRead = read2 (port, buf, 100, ec);
        std::cout << "eport::read: result: " << buf << std::endl;
    }
    catch (error_code &ec)
    {
        std::cout << "eport::read: ERROR: " << ec << std::endl; 
        return "error";
    }

    std::cout << "eport::read: SUCCESS" << std::endl;

    return std::string(buf, numCharsRead);
}
```

Note the difference in the `return`.  A std::string is constructed from the character array, but only up to `numCharsRead` characters.

Comment: ok, I did not know it would do that automatically, thank you; I thought boost::asio::read puts the result into buf

Comment: I should make it bigger then, 1024; and do buf.length () to see how big it is?

Comment: There's no real need to "invent" other API's like `read2`. The available API is documented (see my answer)